# Styling MenuItem within Select component

Tags: material-ui

I am having a bit of a trouble figuring out what css selectors to use to style the menuItem inside of my Select component.

I am using Mui styled. I created a styled component Form Box that wraps around my Select component. I was able to use a className "menu" to style the select component in my styled file, but I am trying to style the MenuItems themselves. I have tried using classNames + MuiMenuItem-root to select, but none of the styles are updating. I am new to MUI so sorry if this question seems silly. I can update some properties using sx but I would like to create a className and style within my styles file.

Appreciate any insight as well as any other resources you have for me to read on!

Here is my JSX:

```
<FormBox component="form" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <h2>Which of our Plant Companions did you take home?</h2>
            <InputLabel className="label" id="select-plant">select</InputLabel>
                <Select
                className="menu"
                labelId="select-plant"
                id="plant_id"
                name="plant_id"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values["plant_id"]}
                label="plantselection"
              
                >
                  {plants.map((plant) =>{
                    return(<MenuItem className="items" key={plant.id} 
                            value={plant.id}>
                                {plant.name}
                            </MenuItem>)})}
                </Select>
            <h2>We aim to earn your 5-star rating, please share your thoughts with us!</h2>
            <Rating sx={{marginTop:"50px"}}
                id="rating"
               name="rating"
               type="number"
               value={Number(formik.values["rating"])}
               onChange={formik.handleChange}
               className="rating"
               
               
            />
            <p>{formik.errors['rating']}</p>
           <Box>
               <Box>Please tell us about your experience with your purchase</Box>
               <TextField
                    id="comment"
                    name="comment"
                    label="Multiline"
                    multiline
                                            
                    value={formik.values["comment"]}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    
                />
                <p>{formik.errors['comment']}</p>
                
                <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
          </Box>
```

Comment: In the browser debugger, in the Elements item, you can see which style classes are installed for your components.